# Pandas str.count

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe. I want to count the number of '$' that appear in a string. I use the `str.count` function in pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['$$a', '$$b', '$c'], columns=['A'])
>>> df['A'].str.count('$')
0    1
1    1
2    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

I was expecting the result to be `[2,2,1]`. What am I doing wrong?

In Python, the `count` function in the string module returns the correct result.

```
>>> a = "$$$$abcd"
>>> a.count('$')
4
>>> a = '$abcd$dsf$'
>>> a.count('$')
3
```

Comment: I didn't even know about `str.count`... thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` has a special meaning in RegEx - it's end-of-line, so try this:

```
In [21]: df.A.str.count(r'\$')
Out[21]:
0    2
1    2
2    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what will happen if df["A"] doesnt have any value, still it is counting

Comment: @pyd, what do you mean saying "`if df["A"] doesnt have any value`"? Do you mean empty DF?

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers have noted, the issue here is that `$` denotes the end of the line. If you do not intend to use regular expressions, you may find that using `str.count` (that is, the method from the built-in type `str`) is faster than its pandas counterpart;

```
In [39]: df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.count('$'))
Out[39]: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [40]: %timeit df['A'].str.count(r'\$')
1000 loops, best of 3: 243 µs per loop

In [41]: %timeit df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.count('$'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop
```

Comment: I don't think it make that much sense to timeit for such a small Series. That said, as it gets larger the difference is even more stark! Edit: Really count should have a regex=False flag like other str methods.

Comment: Fair point. Another commenter actually suggested the same thing before deleting their comment again, so I tried it out with a Series consisting of 10000 random integers; in that case I'm seeing times of about 8.4 ms and 6.1 ms respectively.

Comment: I think there is problem with `None` - `str.count` works and apply no.

Answer (score 2):

Try pattern `[$]` so it doesn't treat `$` as end of character (see this [cheatsheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)) if you place it in square brackets `[]` then it treats it as a literal character:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame(['$$a', '$$b', '$c'], columns=['A'])
df['A'].str.count('[$]')

Out[3]:
0    2
1    2
2    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

taking a cue from @fuglede

```
pd.Series([x.count('$') for x in df.A.values.tolist()], df.index)
```

---

as pointed by @jezrael, the above fails when there is a null type, so...

```
def tc(x):
    try:
        return x.count('$')
    except:
        return 0

pd.Series([tc(x) for x in df.A.values.tolist()], df.index)
```

***timings***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 100000)) \
       .apply(lambda x: '\$' * x).to_frame('A')

df.A.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

def tc(x):
    try:
        return x.count('$')
    except:
        return 0
```

[image]

Comment: But add one notice - in df has to be no `NaN`, then get error. I am not sure, but it seems same problem with `apply` solution

Comment: @jezrael interesting.  will play around

Comment: exactly - test it `df = pd.DataFrame(['$$a', '$$b', None], columns=['A'])`