# how to save sum of str.contains() in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

i'd like to save the number of times Twilight/Sparkle/Twilight Sparkle are found in my csv_file['dialog'] column given that the corresponding cell in csv_file['pony_sort'] is not twilight. i know this is invalid syntax, but is it possible to get what i want this way and if it is, what could i change? thanks!

update:

```
example of data: 
pony_sort | dialog | 
--------------------
twilight  | "....twilight"
applejack | "twilight, twilight, twilight!"
```

in this above example, the first row would not count "twilight" because pony_sort = twilight. the second row would have count = 3 because twilight is not mentioned in the pony_sort column and twilight is mentioned thrice.

```
twilight_mentions = csv_file[csv_file['dialog'].str.contains("Twilight|Sparkle|Twilight Sparkle").sum() for i in csv_file[pony_sort] != "twilight"]
```

Comment: updated. thank you in advance!!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40875649/6692898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind `series.str.contains` counts each row once, regardless of how many of the searched words it contained. What you are looking for is `series.str.count`

```py
from re import IGNORECASE
twilight_mentions = (
    csv_file[csv_file['pony_sort'].ne('twilight')]['dialog']
    .str.count('twilight sparkle|twilight|sparkle', flags=IGNORECASE)
    .sum()
)
```

Output

```
3
```

You could skip the `re` flag if you don't need it.

Notice the order of your optional patterns, if you use your example pattern with `'twilight|sparkle|twilight sparkle'` then a row containing `'twilight, twilight sparkle'` would return 3 instead of 2. However, the pattern `'twilight sparkle|twilight|sparkle'`, tries to find the first option `twilight sparkle` when it encounters `twil...`. I don't know the exact regex implementation but, it is something to pay attention to.

Comment: csv_file is pd.read_csv, is that a significant difference? got an AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: that error was raised because I failed to include `['dialog']` in my previous commit... string accessors are only implemented for series, not for dataframes